Unable to add HorizontalDragTetector to Player class in Flutter Flame
I have a Player class that has movement, I need to add gesture controls so a user can drag their finger left and right to move the player on the screen. From research I have done online it seems HorizontalDragDetector is what I need however I cant figure out how to bring that into my class. Any advice on how I can achieve this goal.
Thank you
Here is the error I get currently
lib/actors/player.dart:13:7: Error: '_Player&SpriteAnimationGroupComponent&HasGameRef' doesn't implement 'Game' so it can't be used with 'HorizontalDragDetector'.
 - 'SpriteAnimationGroupComponent with HasGameRef' is from 'package:eater/actors/player.dart' ('lib/actors/player.dart').
 - 'Game' is from 'package:flame/src/game/game.dart' ('../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flame-1.18.0/lib/src/game/game.dart').
 - 'HorizontalDragDetector' is from 'package:flame/src/gestures/detectors.dart' ('../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flame-1.18.0/lib/src/gestures/detectors.dart').
class Player extends SpriteAnimationGroupComponent with HasGameRef<Eater>, HorizontalDragDetector{

Here is my code
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/events.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:eater/eater.dart';
import 'package:flame/particles.dart';
import 'package:flame/sprite.dart';

enum PlayerState { idle, walk}
enum PlayerDirection{left, right, none}

class Player extends SpriteAnimationGroupComponent with HasGameRef<Eater>, HorizontalDragDetector{

  late final SpriteAnimation idleAnimation;
  late final SpriteAnimation walkAnimation;

  final double stepTime = 0.1;
  PlayerDirection playerDirection = PlayerDirection.none;
  double moveSpeed = 100;
  Vector2 velocity = Vector2.zero();
  bool isFacingRight = true;

  @override
  FutureOr<void> onLoad() {
    _loadAllAnimations();
    return super.onLoad();
  }//OnLoad

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    _updatePlayerMovement(dt);
    super.update(dt);
  }//Update

  void _loadAllAnimations(){
    idleAnimation = _spriteAnimation(7, 'idle');
    walkAnimation = _spriteAnimation(4, 'walk');
    //List of animations
    animations = {
      PlayerState.idle: idleAnimation,
      PlayerState.walk: walkAnimation
    };
    current = PlayerState.idle;//Sets current animation to idle


  }//_loadAllAnimations

  SpriteAnimation _spriteAnimation(int amount, String state){
    return SpriteAnimation.fromFrameData(
        game.images.fromCache('Main Characters/Zombie/zombie-$state.png'),
        SpriteAnimationData.sequenced(
            amount: amount,
            stepTime: stepTime,
            textureSize: Vector2.all(48)
        )
    );
  }

  void _updatePlayerMovement(double dt){
    double dirX = 0.0;
    switch(playerDirection){
      case PlayerDirection.left:
        if(isFacingRight){
          flipHorizontallyAroundCenter();
          isFacingRight = false;
        }
        PlayerState.walk;
        dirX -= moveSpeed;
        break;
      case PlayerDirection.right:
        if(!isFacingRight){
          flipHorizontallyAroundCenter();
          isFacingRight = true;
        }
        PlayerState.walk;
        dirX += moveSpeed;
        break;
      case PlayerDirection.none:
        PlayerState.idle;
        break;
    }
    velocity = Vector2(dirX, 0);
    position += velocity * dt;
  }
}

